# Angular JS : ng-option add "string:" prefix int the option value

Tags: angularjs, forms

Below is my select with `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in getList() ..."> </select>
```

The `getList()` function retrieves the following object:

```
{"CURRENT_ACCOUNT":"test1","ORDINARY_ACCOUNT":"test2"}
```

and if I inspect the generated options, it is the following:

```
<option label="test1" value="string:CURRENT_ACCOUNT" selected="selected">test1</option>
```

As you can see, everything seems right except the `value` attribute has a `string:` prefix.

How can I remove the prefix? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hello! Do you mean "AngularJS" or "Angular"? AngularJS refers to versions 1.x and lower, and Angular refers to versions 2+.

Comment: Looking at the html markup provided for the `select`, i'm fairly certain this is AngularJS, as `ng-options` isn't valid in Angular (v2+).   But good question and lets get the tags updated properly.

Comment: Yes, it is AngularJS (1.x) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong and your code is actually correct.  This is how AngularJS creates the options.

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in getList()"></select>
Selected: {{selected}}
```

If you print out the value of the selected item immediately following it, you'll noticed that the value is just `CURRENT_ACCOUNT` and not `string:CURRENT_ACCOUNT` as the option leads you to believe.

Here is a plunker demonstrating it.

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/lvEi6pknJZMh0wab?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1

Comment: yes, this is right, printing the variable there are not any problem. the issue is caused by the form that is submitted and the "string:" prefix remain in the attribute value. is there any way to escape to haver this prefix?

Comment: So you're submitting the form via the html?  You should instead be doing that using Angular to handle your form submissions via ajax requests (see `$http.post(...)`).

Comment: I'm doing the $http.put(... but the value come to the server with "string:" . any idea?

Comment: How are you serializing the form data to be sent to the server?  Let me update the plunker with a little bit more code to demonstrate how to do so.  Should just be grabbing the object from angular.

Comment: Issue was related to another JS function that is used to prepare the form in case of kana characters. Thank you very much for helping!